# Server binding mode to connect Websphere MQ7 without WAS installed on the same server

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I've being trying to setup my java application that connects to a local queue manager in MQ7 without a WebSphere Application Server installed on my machine in binding mode. Without specifying the host in the .bindings file, running my application will throw an java exception somewhere along the lines of:

> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018:
>   Failed to connect to queue manager 'TBUKKKNN' with connection mode
>   'Client' and host name ''. Check the queue manager is started and if
>   running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see
>   the linked exception for more information.

Although documentation for WebSphere MQ has explicitly denied possibility of connecting to MQ7 without WAS installed on same machine, my colleagues are very confident that there are workarounds for this.

Much appreciated if anyone could help me with this issue. Or let me know if more clarification on my question is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote [an article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0610_woolf/0610_woolf.html) a while back that explains how to do this so I'm a little puzzled about any documentation stating that it can't be done.  Not only is there a "workaround" but it is officially supported and the sample programs that come with the WMQ Client install media include several that use Java and JMS but do not use a Java EE server.  If for some reason you just grabbed the jar files instead of installing the vendor distribution, you can download it for free to get the samples.  The v7.0 client [is here](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC7) and the v7.1 client [is here](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71).  Also, make sure to use the version of the docs that matches your client version.  The v7.0 Infocenter [is here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp) and the v7.1 Infocenter [is here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp).  Any client version can connect to a v7.0 QMgr, by the way.

Anyway, your error message indicates that your Connection Factory transport type is still set to Client.  You'll need to change it to BIND.  The properties are described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm42020_.htm).  The landing page with the list of all the properties of all the administered objects [is here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm10910_.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Change to `cf.setTransportType(MQCNO_STANDARD_BINDING);`  ...that should work

Answer (score -1):

```
cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation?