# Standalone Java JMS app not connecting to WebSphere MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I have a test app that I wrote to send and receive messages across Apache ActiveMQ using JMS.  It's only  a test app so I hard-coded the initial context factory and provider url into a Properties object then put that into an initial context:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
```

And it worked.

Having done that, I now need to convert it to use WebSphere MQ.  I don't have local access to a WebSphere MQ server, for that I need to port it to a third-party machine so I'm working a little blind to get it running locally.

I thought that if I downloaded the client and included the jars in the class path, changed the initial context factory and provider url values, then the app would run, but not connect:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
```

But it doesn't.  I get a naming exception:

> "Cannot instantiate class: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"

I also tried "com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory" with the same result.

I'd like to know the magic string to get this running, or if more fundamental changes are needed, an example of what I need to do.  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497921/server-binding-mode-to-connect-websphere-mq7-without-was-installed-on-the-same-s

Answer (score 0):

Why would you download the MQ Client when you really need the MQ Server?  Un-install it, go and download WebSphere MQ Advanced: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/develop_on_websphere_mq_advanced_at_no_charge?lang=en

Do not try and use Apache MQ code with WebSphere MQ.

Secondly, there are hundreds of JMS/MQ samples on the web. Here's a list: http://www.capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html#jmscode